# Angular 2 Routing - Hide URL

Tags: angular, routes

I know that you can hide the URL when routing using `this.router.navigate(["/Pages"], { skipLocationChange: true });` but when i use `window.open("/Pages")` it has the URL.

Is there any way to hide the URL when using `window.open()` or a way to use the angular2 router to open the URL in a new tab?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found an easy way in the end. `history.pushState({},"Edit","http://localhost:4200/");` works fine for what im after.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the `Location` like this:

```
constructor(private readonly location: Location) {
    //...
}
```

And then in `ngOnInit()` run this:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.location.replaceState("/");
}
```

This replaced the URL in the browser with the URL you specify in `replaceState()`.