# Angular 2/4 Hide Dashboard URL for logged in users

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 2/4 app (and Bootstrap 4 Alpha) with an `AuthGuard` but also an `AnonymousGuard` to prevent already loggedIn users to access certain pages (`/register` `/login` `/forgot`) to redirect them automatically to a `DashboardComponent`.

Everything works perfectly, but I am currently struggling with the displayed URL in the client browser.

At the moment, my `HomeComponent` has a path of `/` and my `DashboardComponent` is `/dashboard`.

But for a better UX perspective, what I want to achieve is to have all our users to see a main `/` URL on both cases :

- Anonymous user : *project.com/* => `HomeComponent`
- LoggedIn user : *project.com/* => `DashboardComponent`

I know I can achieve this by simply conditionally display my `<app-home>` and `<app-dashboard>` elements inside my home HTML using some `*ngIf="isLoggedIn"`, but I am trying to think about a more cleaner Angular/Router way to do this (if it exist ?)

I tried the `{ skipLocationChange: true }` approach in my Guards and routerLinks with no success (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054731/angular-2-routing-without-changing-url)), because if the user is somewhere else on my website, it will somehow keep the previous URL displayed (ex: `/posts/show/`) even if it goes through my Guards.

I also tried to simply hide `/dashboard` by injecting `Location` and use `replaceState` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998677/angular-2-routing-hide-url).

This last approach seems to be close to the result I am looking for, but it doesn't work anymore as soon as the user is clicking a second time on our logo navbar (`routerLink="/"`), because initialization is done.

Am I missing something ? Do you guys have other ideas ? Or should I just resign and go for the simple `ngIf` solution on Home ?
I would be glad to have your reflexion and best solutions on this!

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/tVRKkCQRcNmyc5MIYasM/)

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
 { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
 // other stuff
 { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**anonymous-guard.service.ts**

```
 isLoggedIn: boolean;

 constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private authService: AuthService
 ) {
  this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(is => {
   this.isLoggedIn = is;
   });
 }

 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
  // If Anonymous, can access the page
  if (!this.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
  // Else force redirect to Dashboard
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  return false;
 }
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
isLoggedIn: boolean;

constructor(
 private router: Router,
 private authService: AuthService
) {
 this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(is => {
  this.isLoggedIn = is;
 });
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
 // Original URL is accessible via the 'state: RouterStateSnapshot' parameter
 let url: string = state.url;
 return this.checkLogin(url);
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  return this.canActivate(route, state);
}

checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
 if (this.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
 // Store the attempted URL
 this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
 // Navigate to the login page
 this.router.navigate(['/login']);
 return false;
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(
  private readonly location: Location
 ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.location.replaceState("/");
 }

}
```

Comment: would it be possible to create a plunker for the application that we can test? [here's a template](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue)

Comment: Sure! Will try to make one

Comment: I realise this is **almost certainly** not best practice but did you try pushing the state that you want to display in the url and then routing **with** `{skipLocationChange: true}`

Comment: If I understand well, you mean conditionally change `state.url` in my guards  with something like `if (state.url === "/dashboard") { state.url = "/"; }` then proceed with a `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], { skipLocationChange: true });` ?

Comment: If it does what you want you could try it, although I don't recommend it as a **good** solution: hopefully someone else knows the correct way

Comment: Update with Plunker. Also tried your suggestion but no luck so far (not sure if I tried the correct way though !)